# (Why) does setting `array[NaN]` do nothing?

Tags: javascript, arrays, nan

I was reading [an article about javascript PRNGs](https://medium.com/@octskyward/type-safety-and-rngs-40e3ec71ab3a#.qnb2gsbk4), and I came across something that surprised me:

> ```
> var a = new Array();
> var b;
> a[b++] = 1;
> ```
>
> `a` is now `[]` and no exception is thrown — the write to the array simply vanishes. Try it out in your browser console if you don’t believe me.

I didn't believe him, so I tried it out in my browser console (Firefox 47):

```
» var a = new Array();
» var b;
» a[b++] = 1

» a
← Array [  ]
» b
← NaN
```

There are several curious things going on here, but in particular, I'm trying to understand why the statement `a[b++] = 1` doesn't [appear to] do anything.

Comment: It does - it assigned the `1` to the `a[NaN]`. Try to access `a[NaN]` to see it's there. It's also a slippery road there - you're expecting something from a host object that is not standardised (the `console` is not). So, how do you know what you see is *expected* or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking it from the top:

```
var a = new Array();
// 'a' is now an empty array, plain ol' boring empty array, could have been 
// written as a = [];
var b;
// 'b' have no value and is 'undefined'. 'console.log(b); // undefined'
a[b++] = 1;
// Lets break the above statement down into pieces:
  b++       // Increment b by one, undefined + 1 === NaN
a[   ]      // Use NaN as a property for our array 'a'
       = 1; // Assign 1 to that property
// Ok? So what happened why does 'a' still look empty?
console.log(a); // []
// The way your console with show you an array is by printing the numeric keys
// in it, and looking at the length, eg:
// var q = [];
// q.length = 1;
// console.log(q); // [undefined x 1]

// With 'a' in our case there is no numeric keys in it so [] is printed.
// So did our value dissapear?
// No. It is there:
console.log('NaN' in a); // true
// And:
for (var prop in a) console.log(prop); // NaN

// Why is this even a feature? 
// Arrays are extending Objects so they have the same properties as em.
console.log(a instanceof Object); // true
console.log(a instanceof Array); // true
```

Comment: `Indent b with one, undefined + 1 === NaN`? Why "indent"? And `b++` is not the same as `b + 1`.

Comment: I think I was trying to say: `Add one to b`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of stuff happening there.

1. The code does something - it assigns the value `1` to the `a[NaN]`. And as soon as JS objects can only have string properties - the `NaN` is implicitly casted to a string, so in fact you have assigned `1` to `a["NaN"]` or `a.NaN`.
2. The `console` object is not standardised, so you cannot expect anything particular from it. The current implementation in FF though iterates through the array indexes. `"NaN"` is not an array index, since it's not even numerical, so there is nothing shown in the console.

```js
var a = new Array();
var b;
a[b++] = 1;

console.log(a[NaN], a["NaN"], a.NaN);
```

Comment: @Mgetz a side note: it is first converted to string, so it does not matter if the `NaN` is not equal to itself. "as an index in an array object" --- it's not, index as per the standard can only be numeric (there are more limitations, but in this case those are don't matter).